# Ideal multiplication in polynomial rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $ K = \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n] $ where $ n > 1 $. Say I have two non-principal ideals $ I $ and $ J $, where $ I = (f_1, \dots, f_r) $ and $ J = (g_1, \dots, g_s) $. Then I know that $ IJ = (\prod f_i g_j) $, but is it ever possible for $ IJ $ to be principal? I'm also interested in the specific case where $ I $ is simply $ (x_1, \dots, x_n ) $.

Comment: The answer to the second question is negative.

Comment: @MooS can you elaborate?

Comment: The ideal $(x,y)(x-1,y-1)$ can be generated by two elements.

Comment: You are right, that is not so hard. I have edited the question to make it simpler.

Comment: I have a proof that $(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \cdot J$ is never principal if $J \neq 0$, but it is far from being elementary. It uses depth and the notion of reflexive modules. There should be an easier approach.

Comment: @MooS Is there a simple approach when $ n = 2 $?